# matching vectors by looking for values closest to

Tags: r

I'm trying to come up with a way to join some data together. I would like to take a vector of candidates to join (may exclude some of them) with another vector of candidates (all should be used, or atleast, a failure to find a match should be indicated). I want the join to be 1-to-1. Before I roll up my sleeves and work out an algorithm for this myself, I thought I would ask if the machinery I'm looking for already exists. If not working R code, maybe some well established algorithm? Ideally, I'd like the solution to work with dates as well.

Here are some of the cases I thought would be important to get right:

```
#' # case: all y in xs
#' c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) %>% closest_to(c(4, 5, 6)) # => c(4, 5, 6)
#' # case: all xs in y
#' c(3, 5) %>% closest_to(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) # => c(NA, NA, 3, NA, 5)
#' c(2, 5) %>% closest_to(c(2, 4, 5, 6)) # => c(2, NA, 5, NA)
#' # case: no xs in y
#' c(1, 2, 3) %>% closest_to(c(4, 5, 6)) # => c(1, 2, 3)
#' c(1, 2) %>% closest_to(c(4, 5, 6)) # => c(NA, 1, 2)
#' c(5, 6) %>% closest_to(c(1, 2)) # => c(1, 2)
#' # case: xs is empty
#' c() %>% closest_to(c(1, 2)) # => c(NA, NA)
#' # case: xs is y
#' c(1, 2, 3) %>% closest_to(c(1, 2, 3)) # => c(1, 2, 3)
#' # case: some values shared (revert to minimum distance of maximum length)
#' c(1, 2, 5) %>% closest_to(c(2, 4, 5, 6)) # => c(1, 2, 5, NA)
#' c(2, 5) %>% closest_to(c(1, 3, 6)) # => c(NA, 2, 5) (choose some nice way to handle ties)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I have found some of the answers that can match your questions but the last one.

```
#' # case: all y in xs
#' c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) %>% closest_to(c(4, 5, 6)) # => c(4, 5, 6)
vector1<-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
closest_to<-c(4,5,6)
intersect(vector1, closest_to)
#[1] 4 5 6

#' # case: all xs in y
#' c(3, 5) %>% closest_to(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) # => c(NA, NA, 3, NA, 5)
#' c(2, 5) %>% closest_to(c(2, 4, 5, 6)) # => c(2, NA, 5, NA)
#' # case: no xs in y
#' c(1, 2, 3) %>% closest_to(c(4, 5, 6)) # => c(1, 2, 3)
#' c(1, 2) %>% closest_to(c(4, 5, 6)) # => c(NA, 1, 2)
#' c(5, 6) %>% closest_to(c(1, 2)) # => c(1, 2)

vector2<-c(3, 5)
closest_to2<-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
closest_to2 %in% vector2
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
which(closest_to2 %in% vector2)
#[1] 3 5




#' # case: xs is empty
#' c() %>% closest_to(c(1, 2)) # => c(NA, NA)
c() %in% c(1, 2)
#logical(0)


#' # case: xs is y
#' c(1, 2, 3) %>% closest_to(c(1, 2, 3)) # => c(1, 2, 3)
vector1<-c(1,2,3)
vector2<-c(1,2,3)
setequal(vector1, vector2)
#[1] TRUE


#' # case: some values shared (revert to minimum distance of maximum length)
#' c(1, 2, 5) %>% closest_to(c(2, 4, 5, 6)) # => c(1, 2, 5, NA)
#' c(2, 5) %>% closest_to(c(1, 3, 6)) # => c(NA, 2, 5) (choose some nice way to handle ties)

# No idea
```

Cheers !,